# Hyperlink directs to hidden row

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a workbook that has 2 sheets. Sheet 1 has hyperlinks to several different cells in Sheet 2. The issue is that there are filters in Sheet 2 that will hide rows, so when you try to follow the hyperlink from Sheet 1, the row is hidden and you can't see the target. I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

- On clicking a hyperlink, determine the target row in Sheet 2
- If target row is hidden, unhide the target row in sheet 2, then follow the hyperlink.

It can stay unhidden after the hyperlink is followed, I'm fine with that. I've struggled with this for the past several days, and have come up with nothing successful. I've tried the "Followhyperlink" function, but I think this is too late - it's already followed the hyperlink, so unhiding the row at that point is too late.

Any suggestions? I'm stumped!

Comment: You can probably use the event handler called something along the lines of 'on_click_hyperlink'. Sorry I can't go into more detail but you can do a quick Google search of 'hyperlink events' for more detailed info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FollowHyperlink` is indeed the event handler to use. Put this code in the worksheet module for Sheet1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Dim hyperlinkParts() As String

If ((Target.Type = msoHyperlinkRange) And (Target.SubAddress <> "")) Then
    If (InStr(Target.SubAddress, "!") > 0) Then
        hyperlinkParts = Split(Target.SubAddress, "!")

        If ((Left$(hyperlinkParts(0), 1) = "'") And (Right$(hyperlinkParts(0), 1) = "'")) Then
            hyperlinkParts(0) = Mid$(hyperlinkParts(0), 2, Len(hyperlinkParts(0)) - 2)
        End If

        Worksheets(hyperlinkParts(0)).Range(hyperlinkParts(1)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

This checks that the hyperlink corresponds to a Range object then splits the target address into the sheet name and the specific cell(s). It then unhides the row(s) which correspond to the target address.

The check for the subaddress being empty is needed for hyperlinks to an external workbook where no particular cell is specified

*edit:* this approach won't work for hyperlinks to named ranges and I've altered the code to avoid getting an error message with that kind of hyperlink

*edit2;* code revised to deal with worksheet names containing spaces which were previously causing an error

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately it gives me a Run-time error '9': subscript out of range. The "Worksheets(hyperlink....)" row is the culprit.The hyperlinkParts(0) directs to the correct sheet, and the hyperlinkParts(1) directs to the correct row. I'm not sure what is out of range. Logically, the code makes complete sense. If you have any further thoughts, they would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the specific values of `hyperlinkParts(0)` and `hyperlinkParts(1)` when the error occurs? The documentation on Hyperlink.SubAddress isn't very extensive so there could be some specific format of subaddress that I haven't accounted for

Comment: "All data" (this is the sheet name of the target link) and H2684 (the cell of the target link). If I click a different link (there are about a hundred links), again, the correct address in the above format comes up. There are 21,233 rows of data. Not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: Hopefully fixed now - see updated code in the answer. The problem was that because "All data" has a space in the worksheet name, this ended up enclosed in single-quote characters - `'All data'` - in the subaddress. This causes the Worksheets function not to recognise the name and thus an error occurs. The revised code strips off single quote characters from around the worksheet name

Comment: Wow. Yes, that is fixed now. I'm terribly sorry that I wasn't more specific with the original question and didn't give the actual sheet names. Thank you, thank you. :D